# Get date from days into year (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, date

I am getting the days into the year using this code:

```js
function daysIntoYear(){
  let date = new Date();
  return (Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate()) - Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(), 0, 0)) / 24 / 60 / 60 / 1000;
}
```

Which tells me how many days have passed in the year. From a number like this (it will change), how can I get a `date` object which tells me exactly what month and day and year the day is in.

For example:

an input of 1 should output `(the current year, 2021)` as the year, `January` as the month, and `1` as the day into the month of January.

An input of `102` (the current day) should output something like April 12th 2021.

Is this possible?

Assume the year is always the current year. Thanks.

---

Thanks to @NiettheDarkAbsol in the comments, I was able to solve this using this code:

```js
function daysIntoYear(){
  let date = new Date();
  return (Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate()) - Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(), 0, 0)) / 24 / 60 / 60 / 1000;
}
let finalDate = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 0, daysIntoYear());
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Create a date that is January 100th of the current year. This will be the 100th day of the year.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Thanks! This fixed my problem. If you could add this as an answer, I'd gladly mark it as the answer! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using this code:

```js
function daysIntoYear(){
  let date = new Date();
  return (Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate()) - Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(), 0, 0)) / 24 / 60 / 60 / 1000;
}
let finalDate = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 0, daysIntoYear())
```